# Floating horizontal navigation over slider

Tags: css

I have [this site](http://www.planningmatters.co.nz) with a secondary navigation which I need to float over the top of the slider, or space so that the secondary navigation doesn't go under the slider.

I'm also trying to get the sub-menu grey to go away and to space out better so each item is as long as the words that describe it - does that make sense?

regards,

Answer (score 0):

Use z-index for your sub ul ... something like z-index: 999; that will do

Comment: Thanks Zyad, appreciated ;-)

Comment: I've just added to my question, sorry I should have described goals thoroughly!

Comment: Your structure and css need a lot of work, you just need to work more on that however quick tips would be to remove width and height from the .sub-menu li and the overflow:hidden from the #page

I recommend you read this article it will help you http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu